# Xamarin 5.10.3 installation error (on mac)

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have a problem while running `Xamarin 5.10.3`.

I installed `xamarin 5.10.3` and `MonoFramework-MDK-4.4.0.142` among other dependencies, but I keep getting this error:

[image]

Comment: did you try Xamarin 6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the MonoDroid addin is disabled.

So you can try enabling it in the Add-in Manager or if that is not possible you can edit the following file and make sure the MonoDroid addin is enabled there:

```
~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-5.0/addin-db-002/config.xml
```

If none of the above work I would close Xamarin Studio and then delete the addin database directory:

```
~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-5.0/addin-db-002/
```

Then when you restart Xamarin Studio it will recreate this addin database as though you have installed Xamarin Studio for the first time on your machine.