# Xamarin interface changed to MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I installed Xamarin 5 months ago and it worked good, but now Im trying to open Xamarin in my macbook and i see the interface has been changed to MonoDevelop and just .Net is enabled (Android and IOS is disabled). I attached snapshot
How i can repair it and use xamarin full abilities and potential?

[image]

Comment: Try reinstalling it. Otherwise try the official Xamarin support e-mail

Comment: I would try closing Xamarin Studio and deleting your addin database as described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37665765/268874)